# MVC 3 Override Form Post-Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Wrapped around the axle on this one.  So I have a few buttons within a form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

<input id="create" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Save" />
<input id="create" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Cancel" />    
}
```

What I want to do is when the users click the cancel button, it should hit a different action method which is not the same as in the
begin form. I could have the cancel button outside the form but thats
not an option since its physical placement needs to be close to rest
of the controls of the form.. Or should I use a link button instead of a submit type? Would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As musefan said, you could just make it a link

If you wanted to keep your button you're going to have to get dirty with some jQuery on this one.

The first fix would be to change the id of the "Cancel" button to something like "cancel" instead of "create" (every single element should have a unique ID).

```
<input id="cancel" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
```

Then you need to bind a separate click event to the "Cancel" button to call the different action.

```
$("#cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Keep form from posting
    window.location.href = "REDIRECT URL";

    //If I want to post
    $.post("URL", data { ... });
});
```

Comment: the e.preventDefault(); still posts back to the action method in the form. I am trying to essentially post to the same controller but a different action method and thats not working either. I am doing this: windows.location.href = "RunLogEntry/Edit"

Comment: It does not even hit the javascript function. hmmm

Comment: The code given is in jQuery thus if you don't have the file included in your page then it won't work. Also, you would need to make sure that your cancel button is renamed as suggested. The reason why the form posts is because the event isn't even being called.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to POST any data on 'cancel' then yeah just use a link button with [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) method, for example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "MyAction", "MyController")
```

---

You can also use javascript to change the action of a form:

```
document.myform.action ="/MyController/MyAction";
```

...this would of course require you to handle the click event of the cancel button with javascript